# Why Drupal is faster than WordPress in general

Tags: performance

Some people say that Drupal, in general, is faster(requests per second) than WordPress. I want to know why Drupal is faster. Is it faster because of its cache, sql query or something else?

I see a benchmark here http://sven.webiny.com/benchmark-webiny-vs-wordpress-vs-drupal-vs-joomla-vs-tomatocms/

Comment: I've never heard that, do you have a reference? I'm familiar with Wordpress's codebase as well as Drupal's and my instinct is that Wordpress would definitely be quicker for a basic blog site (which is the only way you can compare Drupal to Wordpress really as the plugins that extend Wordpress to do anything other than a blog site are implemented in a completely different way than Drupal contrib modules)

Comment: @Clive I update my post and provide a reference.

Comment: I'm pretty sure Drupal has been tested here with anonymous traffic which is heavily cached by default, I'm not sure WP ships with a cache hence the difference in performance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's almost impossible to meaningfully compare the performance of Drupal and Wordpress, because their speed varies widely depending on the configuration and installed modules / plugins.  Both are capable of scaling when sites are built by skilled developers.

Regarding the Webiny benchmark, it's almost certain that Drupal's page cache was disabled (the default setting) for the test; I ran the same `ab` command on an Amazon micro instance and got over 100 requests per second.

That said, the Drupal community has a lot of interest in performance (the [High Performance group](http://groups.drupal.org/high-performance) is a good place to start).  The [core development workflow](http://drupal.org/core-gates) has a process to account for performance issues.  And the [ecosystem offers a range of modules](http://drupal.org/project/modules?filters=tid:123) to scale even further, including support for memcached, boost, varnish, APC, MongoDB, CDNs, and others.

Answer (score 0):

Drupal definitely has a leg up in the ability to scale with performance and build upon the core technology. It's framework is more flexible because developers need it to be and are usually more interested, as Dylan mentioned.
Wordpress is faster out of the gate because its users wouldn't really know how to improve it because they don't need to. They aren't interested as much in the best performance, which fits the platform design and use case. I wrote a blog about [performance](http://clikfocus.com/blog/drupal-v-wordpress-website-performance) if you want more information

Answer (score 0):

As they say, "There are three kinds of lies: lies, damned lies, and statistics (or benchmarks)". Ever more so when comparing such diverse CMS as Drupal and WordPress.

This recent (as of 15 March 2024) page shows [PHP speed differences](https://web.archive.org/web/20240315032907/https://kinsta.com/blog/php-benchmarks/) for many various environments, including Drupal and WordPress.

IMHO, an informed decision would be taken by installing both, on exactly same VPS, with similar plugins and themes.